# Updating a custom field in a packaged org updates the namespaced field instead, is there a workaround for this?

Tags: apex, custom-field, leads, sobject

I'm currently testing my application in a packaged org, and am trying to update a field:
custom_field__c of the lead object that i created. I use my app installed in the packaged org to update that field. HOWEVER, my app also has a field of the exact name on the lead. But they should be split between MyApp__custom_field__c and custom_field__c when referencing

This is not the case when I run

```
Lead l = new Lead();
l.put('custom_field__c', 'should be updated');
System.debug(l);
```

the lead is debugged as

```
Lead:{MyApp__Routing_Status__c=should be updated}
```

Has anyone ran into this before? I ran into this because the user org that is using my app happened to have the same custom field on the lead as my app did, and I am trying to figure out a workaround.